# Angular - Multiple column filters for table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table where I want to have an input box below each table header to filter its corresponding column. So I have 2 questions: 1. Between thead tag, how would use the "header" variable as a value for the enclosed ng-model? 2. Between tbody tag, what would be the best approach to specify the column name in the ng-repeat for the filter (filter:{ column_name: model_name })?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="header in tableHeaders">{{header}}<a ng-click="sort_by(header);"></a>
            <div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" class="form-control"/> <!-- value for ng-model should match header variable in enclosing ng-repeat -->
            </div>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:{ Status: search} | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit"> <!-- "Status" should be corresponding column header -->
            <td ng-repeat="header in tableHeaders">{{data[header]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

tableheaders is an array declared in the controller:

```
$scope.tableHeaders = ['Environment', 'Server', 'Name', 'Status'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `tableHeader` values match the variable names they're associated with, make `search` an object having `ng-model="search[header]"` and your filter to just `filter: search`. Keep in mind these are "ands" not "ors", so it matches on all properties of your search object, which may affect how you want to use that search object. Maybe reset it to null in your header `ng-click`.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="header in tableHeaders">{{header}}<a ng-click="sort_by(header);"></a>
            <div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="search[header]" ng-change="filter()" class="form-control"/> <!-- value for ng-model should match header variable in enclosing ng-repeat -->
            </div>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter: search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit"> <!-- "Status" should be corresponding column header -->
            <td ng-repeat="header in tableHeaders">{{data[header]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was lookign for. Thanks! Quick question, in the "filter: search" how does it know which column to filter? I would assume it would require something like "filter: search[header]"

Comment: it maps the properties of the search object to the properties of the searched objects, eg if you have `$scope.search = {mobile:2345678989}` and an array of `persons`, each person having a `mobile` property, it will map `search.mobile` to `person.mobile` as it scans `persons`.